# PAM interface return permission denied when process run with Valgrind

Tags: valgrind, pam

I am running one process and authenticating each request using PAM interface from LINUX user database. it is working fine,
But when running same process under Valgrind, authentication is failing,
All process are running as SDL user and even when running process with Valgrind, then also all process running as SDL

Can Some help, why does authentication is failing when process run under valgrind.

Comment: Does valgrind print outputs during the running of your process?

Comment: when i run my testcase then in log i can check authentication failed,

Comment: And what are the errors or warning of valgrind?

Comment: i am able to resolve, it was process permission, when i run my process as root user then it worked fine, i think, when running process as different user then that process is not allowed to access /etc/shadow(but it is my guess)

Comment: So you can add an answer to your own question, and mark it as the "accepted answer" and raise your own reputation here ;-)